# JS - pause play in setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

im searching for a simple way to make a start stop buttons in setInterval function. but when the stop works, the start doesnt...

```
var zman = 3000;
function pls() {
    setTimeout(setInterval, zman);
}

var myVar = setInterval(function() {
            var sz;
            sz = Math.floor((Math.random() * 750) + 1);
            document.getElementById("fsize1").style.fontSize = sz+"%";
            console.log(sz);
            }, zman);
```

and

```
<button onclick="pls()">play</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(myVar)">Stop</button>
```

whats wrong? and who can i make a play button when i also want the function to run on the first loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pls()` you're asking for `setInterval()` to be called after 3 seconds. Calling `setInterval()` with no parameters will do nothing (although there should be an error in your JS console).

You want to define your function once, then call it both when clicked, and at first run:

```js
var zman = 3000,
  myVar = null;

function pls() {
  if (! myVar)
    myVar = setInterval(sizer, zman);
}

function sizer() {
  var sz = Math.floor((Math.random() * 750) + 1);
  document.getElementById("fsize1").style.fontSize = sz + "%";
  console.log(sz);
}

myVar = setInterval(sizer, zman);
```

```html
<button onclick="pls()">play</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(myVar); myVar = null;">Stop</button>

<div id="fsize1">test<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line var myVar = setInterval(...) runs as soon as the JavaScript loads.  But when the play button is pressed, the setInterval function runs again, but this time without any variable referencing it.  So clicking stop would stop the first interval that was started, but since there is no reference to the variable set when clicking play, there is no way to stop it once it gets set.

Try something like this:

```
var zman = 3000,
    myVar,
    setFunction = function(){
        clearInterval(myVar);
        myVar = setInterval(function() {
            var sz;
            sz = Math.floor((Math.random() * 750) + 1);
            document.getElementById("fsize1").style.fontSize = sz+"%";
            console.log(sz);
        }, zman);
    },
    clearFunction = function(){
        clearInverval(myVar);
    };

setFunction();
```

and

```
<button onclick="setFunction()">play</button>
<button onclick="clearFunction()">Stop</button>
```